# Finding the Integral of a function

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \dfrac{1}{9+x^2}dx$

The answer is $\arctan(x/3)/3 + C$ , but  I don't understand the process of how the answer was found. I tried using u-substitution, but I came up with 2xdx/x^2+9.

Comment: Use the substitution $x=3u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an example of an identity

It is known that

$$\int \frac{1}{a^2+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\frac{x}{a}+c$$

Ss what is $a$?

Comment: Would x equal three?

Comment: No, $x$ would be $x$.

Comment: I meant to say a. would a = 3?

Comment: Yes, $a$ would equal $3$.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the substitution $x = 3\tan(\theta)$, $dx = \sec^2(\theta)\, d\theta$.

Comment: IMO such an answer is quite pointless is you do not motivate the choice of substitution. If you need to just learn by rote that "such and such integral can be solved using such and such substitution", then you might as well instead learn by heart their primitives; this would be faster and avoid computational error in applying the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the relation 
$$
\tan'x = 1 + \tan^2x
$$
The integral is
$$
\int \frac{dx}{9 + x^2}
= \frac13\int \frac{\frac 13dx}{1 + \frac {x^2}9}
$$
now in order to use the relation, substitute $$\frac {x^2}9 = \tan^2 t
\implies \frac13x = \tan t
$$
Then
$$
\frac13\int \frac{\frac 13dx}{1 + \frac {x^2}9} =
\frac13\int \frac{\tan' t\times dt}{1 + \tan^2 t} = \int\frac{dt}3  
\\=
\frac t3 + const.
= \frac13\arctan\frac t3 + const.
$$